# Training a model where true value is only known in batches

Tags: machine-learning, boosting

I would like a model to learn a function $f(x) = y$ based on some data, but suppose that I only know the true value in small batches. More precisely, each training sample consists of $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ for some $n$ (which can vary) and I only know the value of $y_1+\cdots+y_n$.

My goal would be to have a function $f$ which minimizes
$$|\sum_{i=1}^n (f(x_i) - y_i)|$$
for a random batch $(x_i,y_i)$. Can I train such a model using xgboost (or some other model)?

Comment: If you only know $y=\sum y_i$ in the batch, why do you have separate samples? Why not concat all features to one $x$ and use one target value, $y$ and train as usual?

Comment: @gunes Since $n$ is varying for different batches, the number of features would be different for each combined sample. Also I want to stress the fact that $y_i$ is a function of $x_i$ but setting $f(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=y$ would make for a much more complicated function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TLDR:** You could this with a standard ML method (like xgboost) assuming fixed batch size but it is likely to be *extremely* data inefficient. One could code up a Tensorflow model relatively easily that actually does this efficiently and allows for varying batch sizes.

Stepping back from this problem, we can think of what our data looks like. We could think of batches of rows of data where we don't know the label of each row, or we could think of each batch as a single row of data and we do have a label that is the sum of the labels we care about. Thinking of each batch as a single row, our features now look like

$X_i = (x_{i,1}, x_{i, 2}, ..., x_{i, n})$

and we have observed label

$Y_i = \sum_{i=n} y_i$

How do we solve this?

**Standard ML model:** *This requires fixed batch sizes*.

With this framework, we can now learn a simple mapping $g(X)$ from $\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Feed your batches/rows into your model and learn the mapping. Once you learn that mapping, you can extract $f$ by evaluating $g(X)$ along a grid of values where $x_{i,1} = x_{i, 2} = ... = x_{i,n}$ and then divide your predictions along this grid by n, since the true $g(X) = f(x_{i,1}) + ... + f(x_{i,n})$.

**Tensorflow custom model approach:** *This does not require fixed batched sizes*.

Theoretically, with enough data, properly flexible ML model and fixed batch sizes, the method above should converge to the correct answer. However, it's not leveraging as much model structure as it can, and this likely to make it *very* inefficient, especially for large batches! In particular, it's not using the facts that

1. All features are treated exactly the same, i.e. we don't need to learn $n$ different functions for each item of the batch
2. We know that we will be summing the independent inputs of each row.

These two facts *greatly* reduce the space of functions we need to consider and thus leveraging this properly is likely to make for a **much** more data-efficient approach.

I'm not aware of any published models that current take advantage of such structure, but it would be pretty easy to code one up in tensorflow if we again use the converting batches to rows method. All you would need to is code up something like this psuedocode (note: this definitely won't work but I think convey's the idea):

```
def call(self, inputs):
  """Predict Y = sum(y) from one batch"""
  n_cols = inputs.shape[1]
  # Note: n_cols may vary for different batches!
  Y_hat = 0
  for i in range(n_cols):
    # Need to define functional form of learned_f
    # during model initialization
    Y_hat += self.learned_f(inputs[:,i])
  return(Y_hat)
```

You do need to pick what your `learned_f` will be: this could be a simple feed forward network or better yet a bs_spline (assuming $x_{i,j}$ is univariate).

Now we are fully leveraging the known model structure and this should be *much* more data efficient than the standard ML model approach. Also, there's no need for the batch size to be fixed: we simply sum over each input regardless.  Final bonus: you can directly query `learned_f` instead of needing to transform $\hat g(X)$ to $\hat f(x)$.

**EDIT**: I've added an example of doing this with [Tensorflow](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1_Hd4dNOS1_NJ_y3LQMcCdtLGNzMYlsBv#scrollTo=jEh1qyIu5fSj) with a cubic polynomial as the learned function.

Comment: OP specified that the batches are _not_ of the same size: "which can vary" parenthetical note in the question, and again in the comment https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/643886/training-a-model-where-true-value-is-only-known-in-batches#comment1203617_643886

Comment: @BenReiniger: right the tensorflow solution has no problem with varying batch sizes. Changing the answer to emphasize this.

Comment: This might work if there are many batches where $x_{i,1} = x_{i, 2} = ... = x_{i,n}$, but then we might as well use the sum of $y_i$ as target for a simpler model.

Comment: @picky_porpoise: why do you think $x_{i,1}$ needs to be equal to $x_{i,2}$? For the standard ML model approach (which I don't really endorse), for simplicity we feed them back into the model with all features equal so that it's easiest to extract the learned $f$, but there's absolutely no reason they need to be the same during training for either approach.

Comment: If you think of each batch as a row, this just becomes a regression problem with extra known structure to take advantage of. And we certainly don't need $x_{i,1} = x_{i,2}$ for identifiability of regression problems.

Comment: @CliffAB I misread the loss given by OP. I now see that it can be written in terms of $\sum y_i$, so your approach of targeting the sum works.